# Best way to specify one of the existing ManyToMany "through table" relationships?

Tags: django, django-models

I have these models for a database of a library:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  ...

class Task(models.Model):
  ...  # detailed explanation of how the author collaborated in the book

class BookTask(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  task = models.ForeignKey(Task)

class Book(models.Model):
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='BookTask'...)
```

Everything there works fine, but I would like to specify one of the existing BookTask relationships as the main one. Think of one book where 3 authors have worked in. I would like to assign all 3 to the book and then set 1 of them as the main one.

I've tried this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='BookTask'...)
  author_main = models.ForeignKey(BookTask...)
```

But then the generated admin webpage doesn't show the expected select choice widget for the `author_main` field. Any ideas?

(Note: My current solution is adding a boolean field to the `BookTask` model to specify which one is the main one, and controlling through form validation that one and only one of them for a book is selected. It works, but maybe there is a more elegant solution).

Comment: I would say your solution is elegant enough :) it is definitely a good way how to structure the data in the database. Maybe on the frontend, you can present it differently but I would stick with the boolean field in the DB.

_One note though:_ always check for data consistency on the backend! (from your description is not clear where you check for that so I just wanted to point it out :) )

Comment: How about using sequence? You can order the `BookTask` using [order_with_respect_to = book](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) then set the main one as first using `book.set_booktask_order`. The task to validate is deferred to Django's sequencing engine. The drawback is that you need to specify the list of booktask id each time you set the order. IMHO you can try setting only one ID of the main, obmitting the rest to see if Django sequencing all of them the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is the relationship between author/book on one hand and task on the other 1:1? If it is, your solution to add a BooleanField is optimal from database management perspective. Any other foreign key like author_main you have over there will mess up the db schema.

If the relationship is one to many tasks (one author can have many tasks on the same book), I would do this:

```
class AuthorBook(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  primary_author = models.BooleanField()

class AuthorBookTask(models.Model):
  author_book = models.ForeignKey(AuthorBook)
  task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

That way you specify authorship first, and then have tasks mapped to that authorship.

Regardless of the above, you would also need some rule specifying that there can be only one primary author per book. The following SQL query should return result less than or equal to 1:

```
select sum(primary_author)
from AuthorBook
group by book
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You solution is "elegant" enough in most regards.  The part that probably makes you question the solution is having to do validation for relationship data at the admin level, no?

In that case you are correct.  There is a simple way to offload this to the data layer and enforce consistency there instead of at the admin validation level.

Using your example you can enforce the data constraint like so:

```
class BookTask(models.Model):    
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.main:
            self.__class__._default_manager.filter(book=self.book, main=True).update(main=False)
        super(BookTask, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will basically, "toggle" off main on all other `BookTask`s for that `Book`.  This will effectively keep only one "main" `BookTask` for each `Book` in the database.